# Constants in the Rosenthal inequality

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent with $\mathbf{E}[X_i] = 0$ and $\mathbf{E}[|X_i|^t] < \infty$ for some $t \ge 2$.  Write $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.  Then we have the family of "Rosenthal-type inequalities":

$$ \mathbf{E}[|X|^t] \le C_1(t)\cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{E}[|X_i|^t]\right) + C_2(t)\cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{E}[X_i^2]\right)^{t/2} .$$

Henceforth, $c>0$ is some absolute constant.  I have seen in various papers that we can, for example, take $C_1(t) = C_2(t) = (ct/\log(t))^t$.  We can also take $C_1(t) = (ct)^t, C_2(t) = (c\sqrt{t})^t$.  Another option is $C_1(t) = c^t, C_2(t) = c^t\cdot 2^{t^2/4}$.

Is it known whether there is some non-trivial tradeoff curve for the relationship between $C_1(t)$ and $C_2(t)$?  For example, if I'm fine with setting $C_2(t) = (ct^{2/3})^t$, what's the best $C_1(t)$ I can get?

Comment: Hi, Would you mind posting the reference where you got the t/log t and t, `\sqrt{t}` constant? Thanks!

Comment: @ Q. Zeng: Extremal properties of Rademacher functions with applications to the Khintchine and Rosenthal inequalities, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 349 (1997), 997-1027 (T. Figiel, P. Hitczenko, W. B. Johnson, G. Schechtman, and J. Zinn).

Best constants in moment inequalities for linear combinations of independent and 
exchangeable random variables, Ann. Probability Theory 13 (1985), 234–253, 
(W. B. Johnson, G. Schechtman and J. Zinn). 

The simple argument at the beginning of the earlier paper gives something, but not the best $c_1(t)$ for a fixed $c_2(t)$ (Jelani knows this).

Comment: @Bill Johnson: Thanks very much! I found the sqrt(p) and p bounds in a paper by Pinelis and Utev.

Comment: Voting to close to stop MO from resurrecting it every few weeks.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answers below?

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\newcommand{\PP}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf I}\{#1\}}$

According to [Theorems 6.1 and 6.2](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-22/issue-4/Optimum-Bounds-for-the-Distributions-of-Martingales-in-Banach-Spaces/10.1214/aop/1176988477.full), the best constants $C_1(t)$ and $C_2(t)$ are given by
\begin{equation}
    C_1(t)=(c\ga)^t,\quad C_2(t)=(c\sqrt\ga\,e^{t/\ga})^t
\end{equation}
for $\ga\in[1,t]$, up to a universal real constant $c>0$.

E.g., if you want $C_2(t) = (ct^{2/3})^t$, solving the equation $(ct^{2/3})^t=(c\sqrt\ga\,e^{t/\ga})^t$, you get $\ga\sim\dfrac{6t}{\ln t}$ as $t\to\infty$, so that you get $C_1(t)=\Big(\dfrac{ct}{\ln t}\Big)^t$ for some (possibly different) universal real constant $c>0$.

Exact versions of Rosenthal-type bounds for $t\in[2,3]\cup[5,\infty)$ are given in
[Theorems 1.3 and 1.5; see also Proposition 1.2](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-43/issue-5/Exact-Rosenthal-type-bounds/10.1214/14-AOP942.full).

Comment: So you can get $C_2(t) = (c t^{1/2+\varepsilon})^t$ and $C_1(t) = \left(\frac{ct}{\log t}\right)^t$ for any $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: @ThomasDybdahlAhle : Yes, this is true.

Comment: do you have an intuition (or theorem) for when $C_2=(c\sqrt t)^t$ and $C_1=(ct/\log t)^t$ is achievable? Like I suppose it is for simple binomial and poisson distributions. Or maybe that's not even true?

Comment: @ThomasDybdahlAhle : Yes, these constant factors are achievable -- when the $X_i$'s are iid symmetric with a $3$-point support set; see Lemma 6.5 in the first linked paper.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good constant in Rio's Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund type inequality:
$${\bf E} |X|^t \le \left((t-1)\sum_{i=1}^n ({\bf E}|X_i|^t)^{2/t} \right) ^{t/2} $$
for  independent centered $X_i$, $t\ge 2$ . [ 
Rio, E., 2009, Moment Inequalities for Sums of Dependent Random Variables under Projective Conditions, J. Theor. Probab.  22: 146-163. https://doi.org/10.1007/s10959-008-0155-9 ]