# Parameterized simple asymmetric random walk

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Let $ t>0 $, and we look at the random walk $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{n}$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ with $S_0=0$ where $$ \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n}=1\right)    =\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{t}}\right)
$$ $$ \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n}=-1\right)   =1-\mathbb{P}\left(X_{n}=1\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{t}}\right)$$We would like to know when this walk is recurrent and when it is transient, depending on $t$. $S_{n}$ is not a martingale, and we have $ \mathbb{E}\left(X_{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{t}}$. so we have $ \mathbb{E}\left(S_{n}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^{t}}$ which might look look like something we can apply series convergence to, but I didn't achieve much with this approach.

I tried to bound  $ \mathbb{P}\left(S_{2n}=0\right)$: $$ \mathbb{P}\left(S_{2n}=0\right)    =\sum_{s\in S}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{2n}\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}=s_{i}\right)\right)
    \leq{2n \choose n}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}=1\right)\right)\left(\prod_{i=n+1}^{2n}\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}=-1\right)\right)$$
(Where $ S $  is the set of all arrangements of $n$ $-1$s and $n$ $1$s) But this seems like a pretty bad bound, since the sum of it diverges to $\infty $. We also know that $ \mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=1\right)=1$, so we can change ${2n \choose n}$ to ${2n-1 \choose n}$, but this doesn't achieve much either. (and anyway, the above bound isn't that easy to work with)

My current attempt is to bound $ \mathbb{P}\left(S_{2n}=0\right)$ from above with $ \mathbb{P}\left(S_{2n}=0\right) \leq p_n$, with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{n}<\infty$  which implies $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(S_{2i}=0\right)<\infty$ and then using Borel–Cantelli lemma we will get $\mathbb{P}\left(S_{2i}=0\quad\text{i.o.}\right)=0$. But all of my attempts to get a bound which is (1) convergent (2) easy to work with, have failed.

Comment: You can try applying the bounded 4th moment version of the strong law of large numbers,and then show that $S_n/n$ goes to zero almost surely. This would establish recurrence, but may depend on the exact value of $t$ itself. Or chernoff bound may help.

Comment: @kodlu Yes, the result should depend on the value of $t$. I'll try looking into the bounded 4th moment version of the SLLN. How would I use chernoff here?

Comment: I have added yet another answer, with more elementary arguments for $t<1/2$ and for $t>1$. Note also that you did not specify methods of proof in your post at all. So, your question has now been answered fully in 2.5 ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that a random walk (or a Markov chain in general) is called recurrent if it almost surely (a.s.) returns to the initial state infinitely often.

We will show that in our case the walk is recurrent iff $t\ge1/2$.

The key here is the law of the iterated logarithm. Indeed, according to (say) [Theorem 1 of Chapter X](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65809-9) (see the statement of this theorem reproduced at the end of this answer),
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &\limsup_n\frac{S_n-ES_n}{\sqrt{2n\ln\ln n}}=1,\\ 
    &\liminf_n\frac{S_n-ES_n}{\sqrt{2n\ln\ln n}}=-1 
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
a.s.

Also, if $t\ge1/2$, then
\begin{equation*}
    ES_n=\sum_{i=1}^n EX_i=\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i^t=O(n^{1/2})=o(\sqrt{2n\ln\ln n}), 
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$), so that, by \eqref{1},
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &\limsup_n\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n\ln\ln n}}=1,\\ 
    &\liminf_n\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n\ln\ln n}}=-1  
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation*}
a.s., which implies that the walk is recurrent (because it cannot jump over $0$: If $S_k<0<S_m$ for some natural $k$ and $m$, then $S_j=0$ for some natural $j$ between $k$ and $m$).

If now $t<1/2$, then
\begin{equation*}
    ES_n=\sum_{i=1}^n EX_i=\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i^t\asymp n^{1-t},
\end{equation*}
so that, by \eqref{1}, $S_n-ES_n=o(ES_n)$ a.s. and hence $S_n\sim ES_n\to\infty$ a.s., which implies that the walk is not recurrent.

Thus, the walk is recurrent iff $t\ge1/2$. (Basically, it all depends on how $n^{1-t}$ asymptotically compares with $\sqrt{n\ln\ln n}$)

---

**The formulation of the law of the iterated logarithm used in this answer:**

> Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ be independent zero-mean random variables with $s_k^2:=EY_k^2<\infty$ for all $k$. Let $T_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$ and $B_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n s_k^2$. Suppose that $B_n\to\infty$ and for some sequence $(M_n)$ of positive constants we have $|Y_n|\le M_n$ for all $n$ and
> \begin{equation*}
>     M_n=o\Big(\sqrt{\frac{B_n}{\ln\ln B_n}}\Big). 
> \end{equation*}
> Then
> \begin{equation*}
> \begin{aligned}
>     &\limsup_n\frac{T_n}{\sqrt{2B_n\ln\ln B_n}}=1
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation*}
> a.s.

We used this result for $Y_n:=X_n-EX_n$.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to find a more elementary approach for this problem. Theorem 1 of chapter 1 seems unrelated ("let f(t) be a c.f. and let b and c < 1...")? I also don't know  the law of the iterated logarithm (but will look into it), but Wikipedia says it requires for X_i to be i.i.d which is not the case here (but maybe the said Theorem 1 solves this problem?).

Comment: @Jeremiah : (i) I have corrected the mistyped chapter number, and also reproduced the statement of the law of the iterated logarithm (which does not require the iid condition). (ii) If you re-read the answer, you will see that the law of the iterated logarithm (LIL) is, not only the key for the solution, but also essential for understanding of what is going on here. (iii) The proof of the LIL in Petrov's book is rather elementary and short, and the LIL should be in the tool box of every probabilist.

Comment: @Jeremiah : Do you have a further response to this answer and my comment, as well as a response to the other answer?

Comment: @losif Pinelis Thank you very much for your extensive support. I am looking for much simpler approaches, with general known theorems (which are not a specific reference from a certain book), for that, limiting $t$ to a certain interval will help too. Do you have any recommended approach for this?

Comment: @Jeremiah : Have you considered a possibility that there are simply no "much simpler approaches" that could succeed? The tools used in my answers -- a law of the iterated logarithm (LIL), a local limit theorem (LLT), Rosenthal's inequality -- are standard tools in probability theory. I gave references just in case you might not know them (and you did say you did not know the LIL). It seems you wanted to estimate $P(S_{2n}=0)$. In general, this is exactly what the LLT's are for.

Comment: Previous comment continued: That your $X_i$'s are a bit special will hardly help overall. However, the case $t>1$ is easy and can be handled by more elementary means. In the case $t<1/2$ I think we can use one of Hoeffding's inequalities instead of Rosenthal's (used in the other answer), if that is OK with you. So, would it be enough for you to have such solutions for $t>1$ and $t<1/2$?

Comment: @losif Pinelis Yes, excluding the interval $[0.5, 1]$ will be a good start. I tried using Hoeffding's inequality, which got me to the bound:   $$ \mathbb{P}\left(S_{2n}=0\right)\leq 2\exp\left(-\left(\frac{\left(\left(2n\right)^{1-t}-1\right)}{\left(2\sqrt{n}\right)\left(1-t\right)}\right)^{2}\right) $$ which I am not sure is a good bound, and if it is, I don't know how to show that its sum converges (the first thought is the integral test, but this is not easily integrable).

Comment: @Jeremiah : It should be clear at this point that there is no way to estimate $P(S_{2n}=0)$ well enough in the moderate deviation zone corresponding to $t\in[1/2,1]$ other than by a local limit theorem. So, I have to repeat my question: Would it be (not a starting point but) **enough** for you to have the more elementary solutions mentioned in my previous comment for $t>1$ and $t<1/2$? By the way, Rosenthal's inequality can be easily derived from one of Hoeffding's.

Comment: @losif Pinelis Yes, it will be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a random walk (or a Markov chain in general) is called recurrent if it almost surely (a.s.) returns to the initial state infinitely often.

The previous answer, which showed that the walk (in question) is recurrent iff $t\ge1/2$, was based on a direct application of the law of the iterated logarithm, which is in turn based on certain upper and lower bounds on probabilities of large (or, rather, so-called moderate) deviations of sums of independent random variables.

The "My current attempt [...]" edit and a comment by the OP subsequent to the previous answer seem to suggest that the OP prefers an indirect argument, based on the following criterion (see e.g. [Theorem 13.1](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Egravner/MAT135B/materials/ch13.pdf)):

> The random walk will be recurrent iff
> \begin{equation*}
>     \sum_n P(S_{2n}=0)=\infty. \tag{2}\label{2}
> \end{equation*}

To estimate the probabilities $P(S_{2n}=0)$ accurately enough, we need an appropriate local (central) limit theorem. Let $Y_j:=(1-X_j)/2$, so that $Y_j$ takes values in the set $\{0,1\}$ and $P(Y_j=0)=\frac12\,(1+\frac1{j^{t}})>\frac12\,(1-\frac1{j^{t}})=P(Y_j=1)$. Let $T_{2n}:=\sum_{j=1}^{2n}Y_j=n-S_n/2$. Applying now [Theorem 4 of Chapter VII](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65809-9) (with the $Y_j$'s in place of the $X_j$'s), we get
\begin{equation*}
    P(S_{2n}=0)=P(T_{2n}=n)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi B_{2n}}}\,\exp\Big(-\frac{(n-M_{2n})^2}{2B_{2n}}\Big)
    +O(1/B_{2n}), 
\end{equation*}
where $B_{2n}:=\sum_{j=1}^{2n}E(Y_j-EY_j)^2\sim n/2$ and $M_{2n}:=\sum_{j=1}^{2n}EY_j=n-ES_{2n}/2$.

Consider first the case $t\ge1/2$. Then
\begin{equation*}
    0\le ES_{2n}=\sum_{i=1}^{2n} EX_i=\sum_{i=1}^{2n} 1/i^t\le\sum_{i=1}^{2n} 1/i^{1/2}\sim2\sqrt{2n}
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$). So, for some $u_n\in[0,1]$,
\begin{equation*}
    P(S_{2n}=0)=\frac{1+o(1)}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\,e^{-2u_n}
    +O(1/n)\asymp\frac1{\sqrt n}. 
\end{equation*}
So, if $t\ge1/2$, then \eqref{2} holds and hence the random walk is recurrent.

It remains to consider the case $t<1/2$. Then write
\begin{equation*}
    P(S_{2n}=0)\le P(S_{2n}\le0)=P(S_{2n}-ES_{2n}\le-ES_{2n}) 
    \le\frac{E|(S_{2n}-ES_{2n}|^p}{(ES_{2n})^p}
\end{equation*}
for real $p>0$. If $p\ge2$, then, by [Rosenthal's inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/a/298563/36721), $E|S_{2n}-ES_{2n}|^p=O(n^{p/2})$. Letting now $p=\dfrac2{1/2-t}$, we get
\begin{equation*}
    P(S_{2n}=0)=O\Big(\frac{n^{p/2}}{n^{(1-t)p}}\Big)=O\Big(\frac1{n^2}\Big). 
\end{equation*}
So, if $t<1/2$, then \eqref{2} does not hold and hence the random walk is not recurrent.

Thus, indeed the walk is recurrent iff $t\ge1/2$. $\quad\Box$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\ep\epsilon$The OP, who wanted more elementary arguments, agreed that the cases $t<1/2$ and $t>1$ would be enough. Therefore I am providing the third answer to the question, with more elementary arguments for $t<1/2$ and for $t>1$.

Consider first the case $t<1/2$. We have
\begin{equation*}
    ES_{2n}=\sum_{i=1}^{2n} EX_i=\sum_{i=1}^{2n} 1/i^t\ge c n^{1-t}  
\end{equation*}
for some real $c>0$ and all $n$.
So, by Hoeffding's inequality (see the [second displayed inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#Statement), with $a_i=-1$, $b_i=1$, $t=ES_{2n}$),
\begin{equation}
    P(S_{2n}=0)\le P(S_{2n}\le0)=P(S_{2n}-ES_{2n}\le-S_{2n}) \\ 
    \le2\exp\Big(-\frac{2c^2n^{2(1-t)}}{4n}\Big)
    =2e^{-(c^2/2)n^{1-2t}}=O(1/n^2). 
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_n P(S_{2n}=0)<\infty 
\end{equation*}
and hence the walk is not recurrent, if $t<1/2$.

Consider now the case $t>1$. Let $U_1,U_2,\dots$ be independent random variables (r.v.'s) each uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$. Without loss of generality, $X_j=1(U_j<\frac12\,(1+\frac1{j^t}))-1(U_j>\frac12\,(1+\frac1{j^t}))$ for all natural $j$.
Let $Y_j=1(U_j<\frac12)-1(U_j>\frac12)$ for all natural $j$, so that
the $Y_j$'s are independent r.v.'s with $P(Y_j=1)=P(Y_j=-1)=1/2$ for all $j$. Let
$T_k:=\sum_{j=1}^k Y_j$.

Take any real $\ep>0$. Then
\begin{equation}
    p_n:=P(\exists j\ge2n\ X_j\ne Y_j)\le\ep
\end{equation}
for some natural $n=n_\ep$, because
\begin{equation}
    p_n\le\sum_{j\ge 2n}P(X_j\ne Y_j)=\sum_{j\ge 2n}\frac1{2j^t}\to0
\end{equation}
as $n\to\infty$.

Let "i.o." mean "for infinitely many natural $m$ such that $m\ge n$". Since the Markov chain corresponding to the $Y_j$'s is irreducible and recurrent, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    1&=P(T_{2m}=T_{2n}-S_{2n}\ i.o.) \\ 
    &=  P(T_{2m}-T_{2n}+S_{2n}=0\ i.o.) \\ 
    &\le P(S_{2m}-S_{2n}+S_{2n}=0\ i.o.)+P(\exists m\ge n\ T_{2m}-T_{2n}\ne S_{2m}-S_{2n} ) \\ 
    &\le P(S_{2m}-S_{2n}+S_{2n}=0\ i.o.)+p_n \\ 
    &=P(S_{2m}=0\ i.o.)+p_n \\ 
    &\le P(S_{2m}=0\ i.o.)+\ep,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
so that $P(S_{2m}=0\ i.o.)\ge1-\ep$, for each $\ep>0$. So, $P(S_{2m}=0\ i.o.)=1$. That is, the walk is recurrent, if $t>1$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: From what follows the $O(1/n^2)$? Taylor expansion?

Comment: @Jeremiah : One way to deal with this is to show that the function $0\le x\mapsto x^2e^{-Cx^p}$ for $p>0$ and $C>0$ is bounded.

Comment: It seems obvious, but why does $\sum_{n}P\left(S_{2n}=0\right)=\infty$ imply that the walk is recurrent? We can't use Borel–Cantelli, as the events are dependent.

Comment: @Jeremiah : The Borel–Cantelli lemma is not used here. Rather, we use here the well-known criterion for recurrence for Markov chains. A link (https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135B/materials/ch13.pdf) to this criterion was provided in this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/429761/36721

Comment: Well I saw it earlier too, but there is no proof for this criterion in the referenced link. Also, we didn't use any Markov chain property in these proofs, so I am wondering if there is a simple method to justify that it is recurrent without using it too.

Comment: @Jeremiah : (i) A very short and simple proof **is** given there (right before the statement of linked Theorem 13.1). Please be more careful. (ii) Recurrence **is** a property of states of Markov chains. Why then refuse to use "any Markov chain property"? Also, I did give a proof via the the law of the iterated logarithm, without using Markov chains. (iii) You can hardly ever get anything of value in probability theory without using any of its standard tools. (iv) Recall again that in your post you did not specify anyhow any methods you wanted to be used to obtain your desired result.

Comment: Doesn't the proof in the referenced link uses the assumption that the walk is symmetric, or at least with a constant $p$? Both are not true here. For example the claim "at every visit to $i$, the probability of never visiting $i$ again is $1 − f_i$" is not true for asymmetric walks such as the one discussed here. So this proof is not working here to the best of my understanding.

Comment: The second proof which uses expectation looks like a tautology to me. Of course if we have $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(S_{i}=0\right)=\infty$ then we will also have $\mathbb{E}\left(T\right)=\infty$  for $T=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}1_{S_{i}=0}$. Although it seems intuitive that $\mathbb{E}\left[T\right]=\infty$ implies $\mathbb{P}\left(T=\infty\right)=1$, the fact that the events $S_{i}=0$ are not independent makes it hard for me to prove it.

Comment: @Jeremiah : (i) That proof is good for any Markov chain whatsoever. (ii) There is no "second proof" there. In one and the same proof, there are two ways to compute the same: the expected number of visits is $\dfrac1{1-f_i}$ and it also is $\sum_n P_{ii}^{(n)}$. So, $f_i=1$ if and only if $\sum_n P_{ii}^{(n)}=\infty$. (iii) You can find other proofs of this very basic fact in any textbook containing a chapter on Markov chains.

Comment: Look at the asymmetric walk ($X_{i}\in\left\{ -1,1\right\} $): $$ \mathbb{P}\left(X_{i}=1\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & i=1\\
0 & i=2\\
e^{-i} & i\geq3
\end{cases} $$ Then we have $f_{0}\geq\mathbb{P}\left(S_{2}=0\right)=1$ but clearly $\mathbb{P}\left(S_{n}=0\,i.o.\right)=0$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Jeremiah : Did you open any textbook on Markov chains, as I suggested? Did you take time and effort to understand the proofs -- of a very basic and very well-known fact? And now what: Using a probability equal $-1$ to disprove that basic fact? Once again, your posted question has been answered fully 2.5 times. I have also fully answered a great many of your other questions. Can you please take further questions about what you are missing elsewhere, perhaps to https://math.stackexchange.com/ (after giving them a good deal of thought)?

Comment: I thank you very much for your kind and extensive answers so far, and I am sorry it doesn't look like I'm serious enough. The $-1$ probability was of course a typo that was corrected before your comment was posted. I actually did look in texts online, even before asking it in my comment, I was not convinced by the proofs I saw (most of them assumed symmetry), so I asked, which seems reasonable to me.

Comment: For example [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/PDFs/PCMI/PCMI-notes-1) I don't think statement 2.16 is true, for example in the random walk in my comment above.

Comment: @Jeremiah : You are right. The recurrence criterion I cited is for time-homogeneous Markov chains, and the  time homogeneity condition does not hold in your case. I will write down another elementary argument for $t>1$.

Comment: @Jeremiah : I have written down another elementary argument for $t>1$.