# First time random sum exceeds value

Tags: pr.probability, martingales

Suppose $X_n$ $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ are i.i.d random variables with $\mu := \mathbb{E}[X_n]$ > 0. (although they are not necessarily non-negative). Then if $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ and $\tau_a$ = $\inf \{n \geq 1 : S_n \geq a\}$ - so that $\tau$ is the first time that the random sum exceeds the value a. Does there exist some $b,c$ independent of $a$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\tau_a] \leq b+c a$? (or is there even just some way to bound $\mathbb{E}[\tau_a]$ in expectation?)

Additionally we may assume that all moments of $X_n$ exist if needed.

I tried a naive bound using Chebyshev's inequality on $S_n$ to say that it should be close to $n \mu$, and then $\mathbb{E}[\tau_a] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[\tau_a \geq k] \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}[S_k \leq a]$ - however the details don't quite work out.

I also tried considering $M_n = S_n - n\mu$ as a martingale and trying to use optional stopping, but since $M_{n \land \tau}$ isn't bounded from below I also can't quite see how to make it work.

Another idea is trying to use [Walds theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation#Example_with_dependent_terms), but assumption 3 in the wikipedia page gives me the exact same difficulties as trying to use optional stopping

I believe this should be possible, since if we view $S_k$ as the martingale $M_k$ and some drift, then we are in a similar case to Brownian Motion with drift,although our case is discreet. Then the hitting times $\rho_a$ of Brownian motion with drift (which are now continuous) satisfy $\mathbb{E}[\rho_a] \leq c a$, and an explicit pdf can be found.

Comment: "independent of $m$" What is $m$? Is it $a$?

Comment: Also, as $a\to 0+$, it is, clearly not the case: if the first step is negative (which happens with fixed probability), you already have $\tau_a\ge 2$ (and, if we take everything literally, no matter what they are, $\tau_a\ge 1$ for $a>0$, so the expectation is never below $1$). So try to revise the question to exclude various obvious idiotic counterexamples like that :-)

Comment: Are you aware of things like the elementary renewal theorem & renewal theory? Wald's identity lets you decompose $\mu E(\tau)) = a + R_a$, where $R_a = S_{\tau} - a$ is the excess over the boundary. This converges in distribution according to the renewal theorem, and it's expectation also converges. You would want some weak bound on its expectation. I think that can be done and that is is easy with second moments, but maybe harder with fewer. Feller Vol2 has a nice chapter on renewal theory and the first couple of sections of Michael Woodroofe's SIAM

Comment: @Red5551 Welcome to Mathoverflow! :)

Comment: @fedja added some clarifications!

Comment: @mike I have done a course  related to renewal theory but it always had the assumption that $X_n \geq 0 $ and I couldn't see a way to move past that with the material I've studied.

My issue with Wald's identity is you need some kind of assumption bounding $\tau$, for example according to the wikipedia page you would need to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_n| \mathbb{1}_{\tau \geq n}] < \infty$ - and I can't see how to do this

Comment: Certainly $b$ and $c$ would have to depend on the distribution of $X$ (not just on $\mu$). This follows from taking $X_1$ to be $\epsilon^{-1}$ with probability $\epsilon$ and zero otherwise. Then $\mu = 1$ and the expectation of $\tau_1$ is $\epsilon^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\al\alpha$Your desired bound is easy to get if we assume that $\alpha_p:=E|X_1-\mu|^p<\infty$ for some real $p\in(2,3)$.

Indeed,
$$E\tau_a=E\sum_{n=0}^{\tau_a-1} 1=E\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1(\tau_a>n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(\tau_a>n). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Next, if $n\ge2a/\mu$, then
$$P(\tau_a>n)\le P(S_n<a)=P(S_n-n\mu<a-n\mu)
\le\frac{E|S_n-n\mu|^p}{|n\mu-a|^p}
\le2^p\frac{E|S_n-n\mu|^p}{n^p\mu^p}
\le C_1\frac{n\al_p+n^{p/2}\al_2^{p/2}}{n^p\mu^p}
\le\frac{C_2}{n^{p/2}\mu^p};$$
here, $C_1$ is a universal positive real constant, $C_2$ is a positive real number depending only on $\al_p$, and the penultimate inequality is an application of [Rosenthal's inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/a/298563/36721).

So, by \eqref{1},
$$E\tau_a\le\sum_{0\le n<2a/\mu}1+\sum_{n\ge2a/\mu}\frac{C_2}{n^{p/2}\mu^p}
\le\frac2\mu\,a+1+\frac{C_3}{\mu^p}, \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where $C_3$ is a positive real number depending only on $\varepsilon:=p/2-1>0$ and $\al_p$. $\quad\Box$

One can replace the factor $\dfrac2\mu$ in the upper bound on $E\tau_a$ in \eqref{2} by $\dfrac{1+\delta}\mu$, for any real $\delta>0$, but then $C_3$ will have to depend on $\delta$ as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the reference!